# Apply local move using 'cm'

Tags: plasticscm

Using the PlasticSCM command line `cm` tool how do I "apply" a local move detected by `cm status --localmoved`?

By "apply" I mean "change the items status from *localmoved* to *moved* so that a subsequent `cm ci -c "moved some files"` will commit the move.

Things I've tried:

- `cm co newfile` which complains that the file is private.
- `cm co oldfile` which complains that the file does not exist.
- `cm add newfile` which "breaks" the move and turns it into an add and a local delete.
- `cm mv oldfile newfile` which complains that the file does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a command line option to apply a local moved, but there is a *hacker* option in the `move` command that could help here:

```
cm mv src dst --nomoveondisk
```

This switch just move the file in the source control, but not on disk. Then your item should appear as moved. Hope it helps.

### Update

If you want to checkin that changes, you might use the documented option `--applychanges` in the `checkin` command:

```
cm ci --all --applychanged
```

This option will apply local changes first, and then will checkin changes to Plastic SCM server.

Comment: @LumpN: See my edits, there is a non-hacker workaround